# Default Value in datagridviewcombox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to set a default value in datagridviewcombox

```
Private Sub DGVUNSETTLED_DefaultValuesNeeded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowEventArgs) Handles DGVUNSETTLED.DefaultValuesNeeded
        e.Row.Cells("Column1") = "1"
    End Sub
```

My code is not working

Comment: Is `Column1` the actual name of the column object itself? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem. Also can you verify whether or not you're actually using `asp.net`, if not, the tag can be removed as it's not relevant.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592231/set-default-value-for-datagridview-combobox) may be of help as well.